# Php Regex Function To Remove File Reference

Tags: php, regex

I need a php function that will remove and return any references to an excel file within exclamation points. So if I have:

```
$string = "Blah blah blah, this is a paragraph \n\n
           and some more copy. \n\n

           !/uploads/excel_doc.xls! \n\n

           Blah blah. The end."
```

I want to have a function like this:

```
function excel_file($string){

    $string = _[_reg ex filter__]___;
    return $string;
}
```

Where $string returned is:

```
array($original_string, $excel_file_name);

// original string should replace the excel file reference with the string "[excel]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
$string = "Blah blah blah, this is a paragraph \n\n
           and some more copy. \n\n

           !/uploads/excel_doc.xls! \n\n

           Blah blah. The end.";


function excel_file($string){
    preg_match('/!([^!]+)!/m', $string, $m);
    $string = preg_replace('/!([^!]+)!/m', '[excel]', $string);
    return array($string, $m[1]);
}          
$arr = excel_file($string);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blah blah blah, this is a paragraph


           and some more copy.



           [excel]



           Blah blah. The end.
    [1] => /uploads/excel_doc.xls
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove anything between `!!`, try:

```
// Remove any string made of alphanumerics and "_-./" between !!
$string = preg_replace('/![a-z0-9_\\-\\.\\/]+!/i', '', $string);
```

If you want to do that only on xls file paths, try this variation:

```
// Remove any string made of alphanumerics and "_-./" that ends with .xml between !!
$string = preg_replace('/![a-z0-9_\\-\\.\\/]+\\.xls!/i', '', $string);
```

I can't get the part where you say you want to replace it with something else (dont' you said you want to remove?!?). If you can be more precise, I will be glad to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression: `/!((?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+)!/` with preg_match

Here's a site I use to help write regular expressions, which I used to get that expression - http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s=!/uploads/excel_doc.xls!&-29&-28&1

It may help you too. Always double-check the parenthesis on their generated expressions, they always extract more data than you need. Some php code is included as well, if any of that helps.